# Receive text data via Bluetooth in between Android devices in android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am working on an Android app in which I need to transfer text from one device to another device using Bluetooth interface. 
Problem is, MY BROADCAST RECEIVER IS NOT WORKING AS IT SHOULD WORK. When data is sent from one device, Broadcast listener of my receiver device doesn't function at all. 
I am using below code currently:

The below code is to connect to a Bluetooth device:

```
protected void connect(BluetoothDevice device) {
try {
ConfigClass.isFirstBluetoothSignal=true;
Log.d(TAG,"connect bluetooth");
// Create a Socket connection: need the server's UUID number of
// registered
Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket",
new Class[] { int.class });
socket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
// socket=device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID_INSECURE);
socket.connect();
Log.d(TAG, ">>Client connectted");
inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
socket.getOutputStream();
int read = -1;
final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
while (true) {
synchronized (obj1) {
read = inputStream.read(bytes);
//_handler.obtainMessage(RECIEVE_MESSAGE, -1, read).sendToTarget();
Log.d(TAG, "read:" + read);
if (read > 0) {
ConfigClass.isFirstBluetoothSignal=false;
final int count = read;
String str = SamplesUtils.byteToHex(bytes, count);
// Log.d(TAG, "test1:" + str);
hex = hexString.toString();
if (hex == "") {
hexString.append("<--");
} else {
if (hex.lastIndexOf("<--") < hex.lastIndexOf("-->")) {
hexString.append("\n<--");
}
}
hexString.append(str);
hex = hexString.toString();
// Log.d(TAG, "test2:" + hex);
if (hex.length() > maxlength) {
try {
hex = hex.substring(hex.length() - maxlength,
hex.length());
hex = hex.substring(hex.indexOf(" "));
hex = "<--" + hex;
hexString = new StringBuffer();
hexString.append(hex);
}catch (NullPointerException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
Log.e(TAG, "e", e);
}
}
_handler.post(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), hex, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}
});
}
}
}
} catch (Exception e) {
ConfigClass.isFirstBluetoothSignal=false;
Log.e(TAG, ">>", e);
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
getResources().getString(R.string.ioexception),
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
return;
} finally {
if (socket != null) {
try {
Log.d(TAG, ">>Client Socket Close");
socket.close();
socket = null;
// this.finish();
return;
} catch (IOException e) {
Log.e(TAG, ">>", e);
}
}
}
}
```

The below code is to accept incoming connection:

```
public class AcceptThread extends Thread{
// The local server socket
private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;
private String mSocketType;
private BluetoothAdapter mAdapter=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

public AcceptThread(boolean secure) {
BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
mSocketType = secure ? "Secure":"Insecure";

// Create a new listening server socket
try {
if (secure) {
tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME_SECURE, MY_UUID_SECURE);
} else {
tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME_SECURE, MY_UUID_INSECURE);
}
} catch (IOException e) {
Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "listen() failed", e);
}
mmServerSocket = tmp;
}

public void run() {

//BluetoothSocket socket = null;

// Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
while (true) {
try {
// This is a blocking call and will only return on a
// successful connection or an exception
socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
//InputStream ins=socket.getInputStream();

/*BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins));
StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
total.append(line);
}*/

//System.out.println("Data============================================>>>"+line);
} catch (IOException e) {
Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "accept() failed", e);
break;
}

// If a connection was accepted
if (socket != null) {
synchronized (SearchDeviceActivity.this) {

ConnectedThread connectedThread=new ConnectedThread(socket, device.getAddress());
connectedThread.start();
//socket.close();
break;
}
}
}

}
}
```

The below code is to fetch incoming data:

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
private final InputStream mmInStream;
private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

@SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi" })
public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, String socketType) {
Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread: " + socketType);
mmSocket = socket;
InputStream tmpIn = null;
OutputStream tmpOut = null;

// Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
try {
tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
} catch (IOException e) {
Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
}

mmInStream = tmpIn;
mmOutStream = tmpOut;
}

public void run() {
Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytes;

// Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
while (true) {
try {
// Read from the InputStream
bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

// Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
_handler.obtainMessage(SearchDeviceActivity.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
.sendToTarget();
} catch (IOException e) {
Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
//connectionLost();
break;
}
}
}

/**
* Write to the connected OutStream.
* @param buffer The bytes to write
*/
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void write(byte[] buffer) {
try {
mmOutStream.write(buffer);

// Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
_handler.obtainMessage(SearchDeviceActivity.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
.sendToTarget();
} catch (IOException e) {
Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
}
}

public void cancel() {
try {
mmSocket.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
}
}
}
```